# Приведите пример сложных слов с известной второй основой

Tags: сложные-слова

Приведите примеры сложных слов, имеющих вторую основу "видный" (например: стекловидный).

Comment: Берете основу любого существительного, обозначающего объект, добавляете видный и получаете необходимое вам слово. Вплоть до *телевизоровидный* (похожий на телевизор). Другое дело, что не все эти слова зафиксированы в словарях.

Answer (score 2):

Грибовидный, грушевидный, дальновидный, древовидный, змеевидный, клиновидный, миловидный,  палочковидный, пылевидный, роговидный, сердцевидный, серповидный,  стреловидный, шаровидный, яйцевидный и др.